# In a Git pre receive hook, Is there a way to get Repository Origin details like Org and repository name?

Tags: git, githooks

I want to access Git Repository Origin details in a Pre Receive hook, so that I can curl using GitHub repository API and access additional information on the repository.
Can I use git command `git config --get remote.origin.url` in my pre-receive hook scrip to get origin details ?

Comment: Server side hooks are for your own server that uses Git version control. Github does not let you run code on its server. If you elaborate on this- `I can curl using GitHub repository API `, I might be able to help better. What you might be looking for is pre receive equivalent Github **WebHook**, not Git hook.

Comment: I want to be able to access Description of the GitHub repository every time when there is a new change is being update to the repo

Comment: Then you need to configure WebHooks inside GitHub to deliver a nice payload to you everytime a change is made. It is a huge payload well detailed. If you need more information, you need tokens and code to call GitHub API and get this extra information you need.